# c++ function that checks each individual bit for 0 or 1

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with this assignment. I have worked on it yesterday and today with no luck.

***Instructions:*** The function scans word, starting from bit startingBit, toward more signiﬁcant bits, until the ﬁrst zero (0) bit is found.

Next, the function returns the index of the found bit. If the bit at *startingBit* is already what’s sought,  then *startingBit* is returned.

If there’s no bit found, then UINT MAX (deﬁned in climits) is returned. Here is my code.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>

extern const int N = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT; // # of bits in an int

unsigned int scan0(unsigned int word, unsigned int startingBit)
{
    extern const int N;
    unsigned int currentBit = UINT_MAX; // -1 means UINT_MAX, if you see its definition that is

    for (currentBit = startingBit; currentBit < static_cast<unsigned int>(N); currentBit += 1)
    {
         getBits(word, currentBit);
    }
    if (currentBit <<= 0)
    {
        return currentBit;
    }
    if (currentBit != 0)
    {
        return UNIT_MAX;
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int i, x;

    while (cin >> x)
    {
        cout << setw(10) << x << " base 10 = "  << bitset<N>(x) << " base 2" << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < static_cast<unsigned int>(N); ++i)
        cout << "scan0(x, " << setw(2) << i << ") = " << setw(2) << scan0(x, i) << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

> My code is saying their is an undefined reference to main.

Comment: Please re-read your question and consider whether that's enough information to work with. You haven't said what's wrong with your code, and your code doesn't compile because there's no `main`. We'd love to help, but we need to understand what isn't working.

Comment: `int getBits(unsigned int word, unsigned int currentBit);` is not a call but a declaration, so it should be `getBits(word, currentBit);`. You need not tell the compiler, the type again...

Comment: @Tas Not having a `main` function does not prevent a C source file from successful compilation.

Comment: @FredMiller Some compilers can complain about the program not having an [entry point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#C_and_C++) so it depends on which type of file you are creating (Application, Dynamic Link Library, Static Library, etc.)

Comment: @Ruks Even for an executable program the entry point may be defined in another source file than the one defining `scan0`.

Comment: @FredMiller Yes that can be done, but that is due to the fact that the compiler compiles all the headers and source files into one binary executable so any other source file will also be the part of the executable after compilation, but that will not change the fact that an entry point is required to run...

Comment: What do you think `if (currentBit <<= 0)` does?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

#define setbit( _b ) ( 1 << _b )

unsigned int scan0( unsigned int word, unsigned int bit )
{
    while( word & setbit( bit ) ) ++bit;
    return( ( bit < ( CHAR_BIT * sizeof( unsigned int ) ) ) ? bit : UINT_MAX );
}

int main( void )
{
    std::cout << scan0( 0xFF, 3 ) << std:: endl;
    std::cout << scan0( ~0x0000, 0 ) << std:: endl;
    return( 0 );
}
```

On my phone no compiler, but your code has a bug with that extern. At first I thought you were trying to say that function lived in some other file. But if they are in the same file why are you trying to make it extern? Extern is kind of like saying “hey anyone who can see this can use this value, but it’s memory actually lives within a different translational unit”. You can’t declare an extern variable and set it in the same declaration; it doesn’t make sense to do that. I recommend reviewing the definition of the extern C keyword.